# Advertise a binding for TeX-next-error in AucTeX

Tags: key-bindings

How can I advertise a binding for TeX-next-error in AucTeX?I
There are several bindings for `next-error`, normally `` C-x `, M-g n, M-g M-n ``. With

```
(put 'next-error :advertised-binding "\M-gn")
```

I will see `M-g n` in the Compile menu in Compilation mode, for example.

In AucTeX’s LaTeX mode I haven’t been able to change the advertised binding for the *Next Error* command in the Command menu, either with the same code, or by using `TeX-next-error` instead, which it really is bound to. How can I do this?

Comment: thanks for the question! TIL: `:advertised-binding`

Answer (score 2):

`next-error` is a function, you want to change a property of a function (not change a property of a variable). So you need to use `function-put` instead of `put`.

```
(function-put 'next-error :advertised-binding "\M-gn")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `function-put` versus `put`.  Either works fine.

The problem is with your representation of the key binding as `"\M-gn"`.  Just use this (with either `put` or `function-put`):

```
(put 'next-error :advertised-binding (kbd "M-g n"))
```

or

```
(put 'next-error :advertised-binding [?\M-g ?n])
```

or

```
(put 'next-error :advertised-binding [(meta ?g) ?n])

(substitute-command-keys "The advertised binding is \\[next-error]")
```

When in doubt use `kbd`.  It's also generally best for human readers, as the string argument shows the key-sequence representation that Emacs shows us in Help etc., generally.

Comment: I don't think that's it either. When just doing emacs -Q, a put-command and then a substitute-command-keys-command, the put-command in the question works just as fine as your alternatives.

But I still don't know how to get this to work in AucTeX (where next-error is remapped to TeX-next-error).

Comment: Not sure I understand you. If `next-error` is remapped to `TeX-next-error` then why would you expect that changing the `advertised-binding` of `next-error` would have any effect? Did you try setting `advertised-binding` of `TeX-next-error`? I guess I'm not completely understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `(global-set-key (kbd "M-g n") 'TeX-next-error)`. In the text menu will change automatically.

Comment: I think you have missed what :advertised-binding is. See (elisp) Keys in Documentation!

Comment: I see..I will..